# There was a problem with my add to cart function. I was unable to add the data into database

Tags: php

My project online  grocery store.
So while adding the products i was unable to add the products into cart.

The below written code is a function for add to cart.
I am unable to get database into the table.I have tried clicking on the products it refreshs but no database is entered.

```php
function cart() {

    if(isset($_GET['add_cart'])) {

            global $con;

            $ip=getIp();

            $pro_id =$_GET['add_cart'];

            $check_pro = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip' AND p_id='$pro_id'";

            $run_check = mysqli_query($con, $check_pro);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($run_check)>0) {

                echo "";


            }

            else {

                 $insert_pro = "insert into cart (p_id , ip_add) values ( '$p_id', '$ip')";

                $run_pro = mysqli_query($con,$insert_pro);

                echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: check your logic, maybe the first select is matching rows (`echo "";` is not helpful), your insert is using wrong var and all is open to sql injection

Comment: Should i remove echo.

Comment: it wouldn't make a difference

Comment: " I am unable to get database into the table." 
This line makes no sence. Did you mean "Add a row to the table instead?"

Basically you are saying  if there is a "add_cart" variable go check and see if there is a row in the table. But you never have a "INSERT" Query to actually insert information. That query will only run without the variable "add_cart"  Maybe you meant to have the logic inverted? 

to change behaviour change the line and add '!':  if(!isset($_GET['add_cart'])) { .. }else{ ... }